# How to change bitcoind 0.8.1 bind settings?

Tags: bitcoind, server, linux

I would like to setup bitcoind to run in the background but not have live bindings.

I have tried the following:

```
bitcoind
bitcoind -server
bitcoind -daemon
bitcoind -daemon -server
bitcoin.conf (server=0)
```

0.8.1 seems to bind to 127.0.0.1:8332, 0.0.0.0:8333, ::1:8332, :::8333

How do i disable all bindings and have bitcoind respond via command line, while maintaining new blocks?
OR
How do i bind only to 127.0.0.1:8332?

Goal: duplicate mysqld behavior.

Comment: IIRC, I think you're looking for the `nolisten` and `rpcallowip` options.

Answer (score 1):

it seems the following is the answer to both questions:

```
// bitcoind.conf, v0.8.1
irc=0
listen=0
rpcpassword=<hash>
```

this results in a 127.0.0.1:8332 and ::1:8332 listen only. i was unsuccessful in locating a command that disables ipv6 listens. the onlynet= command limits peer connection types, not listen types.

listen=0 disables live listens, but does not affect localhost binds.
the bind= command only works if listen=1
note that rpcuser= is set default to root if omitted and only accessible by a user with said credentials. disabling all listens would make the daemon inaccessible by command line. the server= command only works for bitcoin-qt.